# Replace each reoccuring string value of a one line flat json to a random value using python

Tags: python, awk

I have a JSON file (**input.json**) like the following which has **2** rows... (The real one has more than 1m rows)

```
{"one":"A1","two":"B2","three":"C3","four":"D4","five":"E5"}
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"WW","five":"VV","six":"UU"}
```

I want to basically change the value of each and every field with name **four** to a random value, so basically wherever it appears, it will remove what it currently have and change it to a random given value:

expected output:

```
{"one":"A1","two":"B2","three":"C3","four":"random123","five":"E5"}
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"akskaskas","five":"VV","six":"UU"}
```

It could be any random value..

I'm kinda struggling with **python** at the moment, any tips or solutions would really help!

```
from random import choices
import json

with open('input.json') as infile:
  data = json.load(infile)

data['four'] = ''.join(choices('asdf1234', k=10))

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your input file structure, the elements must be on a list, like this:

```
[
{"one":"A1","two":"B2","three":"C3","four":"D4","five":"E5"},
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"WW","five":"VV","six":"UU"},
{"one":"A1","two":"B2","three":"C3","four":"D4","five":"E5"},
{"one":"A1","two":"B2","three":"C3","four":"D4","five":"E5"},
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"WW","five":"VV","six":"UU"},
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"WW","five":"VV","six":"UU"},
{"one":"ZZ","two":"YY","three":"XX","four":"WW","five":"VV","six":"UU"}
]
```

You can change a key value with this:

```
from random import choices
import json

with open('input.json') as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    for i in data:
        i['four'] = ''.join(choices('asdf1234', k=10))

with open('output.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

`choices` method will randomly choose 10 characters from 'asdf1234', `join` will create a single string, and the result will be store into `four` key.

Comment: Yep, but how to give it a random value made up of string and int or whatever :)

Comment: @Saffik, I thought you already did that, anyway, I changed the answer. :)

Comment: `NameError: name 'choices' is not defined`

Comment: Did you import the choices from random packages? see the snippet first line `from random import choices`

Comment: Yes, i did as you said. I have updated my question and pasted your suggested code there. Am i missing an import?

Comment: I need a full example from your input.json file. The dicts are stored in lines or it comes from a list?

Comment: The input.json file is literally as I have pasted it above. It is flat structure json. 1 per each line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214261/discussion-between-diego-magalhaes-and-saffik).

Comment: You don't have to `infile.close()` when using `with` statement.

Comment: Yeah! I refactored this snippet using with and forgot to exclude `.close()` Thanks @AndriyMakukha

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json file consists of a list of jsons, the following might be one solution:

```
import random
import string

# File content:
# [
# {'one': 'A1', 'two': 'B2', 'three': 'C3', 'four': 'D4', 'five': 'E5'},
# {'one': 'ZZ', 'two': 'YY', 'three': 'XX', 'four': 'WW', 'five': 'VV', 'six': 'UU'}
# ]

data = []

def get_random_alphaNumeric_string(stringLength=8):
    lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join((random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength)))


with('filename.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for each in data:
    each['four']= get_random_alphaNumeric_string()

with('filename.json', 'w') as file:
    data = json.dump(data, file)
```

Comment: with('filename.json') as file:
AttributeError: __exit__

Comment: Make sure you get the correct filename and the file path.